# What Apps allow a user to join photos of arbitrary quantity and size?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I was surprised this does not exist and am considering writing the App myself in response. How can you merge multiple photos into a new merged photo?

Like:

**Input**

- 200x300 "A.jpeg"
- 200x500 "B.jpeg"
- 200x100 "C.jpeg"

**Merged Output**

- 200x900 "A+B+C.jpeg"

Thoughts? Do I need to go write this myself :)?

Comment: For example, PhotoGrid, option "Stitch".

Comment: this works, thank you!! Please put this as an 'answer' below and I will mark as solution. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option "Stitch" in [Photo Grid](https://appsto.re/de/mvLzG.i) app allows you to merge multiple photos (up to 9).